# Perform a GET Request in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Well I'd like to perform a GET Request of this URL: `localhost:8080/home/data`. Well if I'd like to access this URL i have to authenticate with a username and a password.

This is my code:

```
     getDataAxios(){
    axios.get('localhost:8080/home/data', {
       
        auth: {
            username: 'user.user@provider.com',
            password: 'password'
          }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
}
```

And if I press a ceratin button on  the React.js website the data which will come from that  url should be displayed on the console. Somehow it is not  working with this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

BTW. The backend is working.  I  verified it with Java.

Comment: How did you import axios?

Comment: import { axios } from 'axios'

Comment: Actually, it is not a named import so you would do `import axios from 'axios'`.

Comment: You may want to show a bit more of your code.  As the previous comments suggest you may not have imported axios correctly.

Answer (score 1):

That error seems to be coming from the axios library, instead of an error in your backend or something. The `Uncaught TypeError` means is that the axios library is not been imported properly, or the scope where you're invoking axios is not accessible. Check that you're importing the library on your React component. It should be something like:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

In the top of your component.

Comment: Now I get this error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8080/home/data' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Comment: You need to install `npm i cors` to access your backend from the client

Comment: @masterYoda: You have to enable CORS from back end using `@crossorigin`

Comment: @masterYoda what backend are you using? Laravel? NodeJS? Express? Can you give me more detail about that? The CORS error is a whole new world that I would have to explain. I recommend you read a little about the CORS means on this post  https://laravel-news.com/using-sanctum-to-authenticate-a-react-spa

If you're not Laravel or PHP developer, you'll understand what it means.